# Elusive etymology, false cognate?

Tags: etymology, greek, cognates

So I just stumbled upon this beautiful word, Eleusinian(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusinian_Mysteries), named after a Greek town. 
Given they had a history of cool initian rites, and all the jazz of ancient cults, I'm wondering if Elusive and Eleusinian have any connection? 
Wiktionary suggests no, can anybody verify? Supposedly "elusive" is derrived from "elude". Does this word have a greco-roman origin?
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elusive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, let me say I'm not sure why your question has so many close-votes: it is directly about the etymology of a word, and so is definitely within scope.

Okay, `elusive` comes more-or-less directly from Latin. Latin has the word `ēlūdō` which apparently can mean "avoided". This word is made up of `ex-` (out of) and `lūdō` (a trick). This is evidence against any direct descendance from Greek, because these elements in turn come directly from Proto-Indoeuropean.

I couldn't find any etymology for Eleusis though. But the most likely explanation is a coincidence.

Comment: The close votes are probably for the sheer unlikelihood, but agreed, it's in scope.

Comment: That's not what close votes are *for*, though. Sigh.

Comment: No, the close votes are because it's a philology question, not a linguistics question.

Comment: @curiousdannii What is **your** definition of philology?

Comment: @AlexB. I'm using it to mean "the study of words" (which is not exactly its real meaning) rather than "the study of languages". Perhaps I should just say it's an etymology question. [Here's what I've said on Meta](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1745/2555).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusinian_Mysteries: "The name of the city Eleusis is Pre-Greek, and may be related with the name of the goddess Eileithyia.[9] Her name Ἐλυσία ( Elysia) in Laconia and Messene, probably relates her with the month Eleusinios and Eleusis,[10] but this is debated.[11]"